# Mechanics problem.

Tags: physics

A bottle is dropped from a blimp whose height is 1200m. Assume that a= 9.81m/s/s, find the time it takes the bottle to reach the ground.

Comment: Just use $s=\frac{at^2}{2}$.

Comment: Abdullah there's a stack exchange site for physics so ask it there!

Comment: @IlayaRajaS This question would be closed as off-topic on [physics.se]

Comment: I say it is not off-topic because it belongs at another site.  I say it is off-topic as a homework problem from a calculus course (not showing any effort on the part of the OP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of the bottle is given by the equation: $s=s_0-\dfrac{1}{2}gt^2$ where $s_0= 1200m $ is the starting point. And it is at the ground whan $s=0$, i.e:  $s_0=\dfrac{1}{2}gt^2$. Solving for $t$ you have $t=\sqrt{2s_0/g}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$a=\frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}t}$

$v=\frac{\text{d}s}{\text{d}t}$

where $a$ is acceleration, $v$ is velocity, and $s$ is position.